# SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 function to pull xml data

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have a function that pulls out a patient number from a `CCD`, however, the `CCD` contains `MRN, EMPI, SSN`, and Patient Number. I need it to pull the Patient Number instead of EMPI. I will then use this to create a column by utilizing the RETURN.

Please HELP!

Here is current code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[rs_ExtractPatientIdentifier] 
    (@xmlData xml, @messageType nvarchar(50))
RETURNS 
    nvarchar(128)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
BEGIN
    DECLARE @patientIdentifier nvarchar(128)

    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://domain.com/product/Schemas', 'urn:hl7-org:v3' as hl7ns)
    SELECT 
       @patientIdentifier = CASE @messageType
                               WHEN 'CCD' THEN @xmlData.value('(hl7ns:ClinicalDocument/hl7ns:recordTarget/hl7ns:patientRole/hl7ns:id/@extension)[1]', 'varchar(128)')
                               WHEN 'PatientAdverseReactionRequest' THEN @xmlData.value('(PatientAdverseReactionRequest/Patient/Identifiers/Identifier/Id)[1]', 'varchar(128)')
                               WHEN 'UnsolicitedDocumentType' THEN @xmlData.value('(DocumentManagementRequest/Patient/Identifiers/Identifier/Id)[1]', 'varchar(128)')
                               WHEN 'UnsolicitedLabResult' THEN @xmlData.value('(UnsolicitedLabResult/Patient/Identifiers/Identifier/Id)[1]', 'varchar(128)')
                               ELSE ''
                             END

    RETURN @patientIdentifier
END
```

Here is the XML with the Patient ID that I need to pull out as Locally defined patient ID:

```
<ProcessCcdRequest xmlns="http://domain.com/product/Schemas">
<Ccd>&lt;ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd"&gt;&lt;realmCode code="US"/&gt;&lt;typeId extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/&gt;&lt;templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/&gt;&lt;templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2"/&gt;&lt;id root="2.25.126274596634328418155136651226877799755"/&gt;&lt;code code="34133-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Summarization of episode note"/&gt;&lt;title&gt;Clinical Document Architecture&lt;/title&gt;&lt;effectiveTime value="20140619191531-0400"/&gt;&lt;confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25"/&gt;&lt;languageCode code="en-US"/&gt;&lt;recordTarget&gt;&lt;patientRole&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="Enterprise MPI Number" extension="000000001" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.1.2.1"/&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="Enterprise MPI Number" extension="000000001" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.1.2.1"/&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="SSN" extension="999999999" root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1"/&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="Hospital: Locally defined Patient Account Number" extension="000222222222" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.44273.7.3"/&gt;&lt;addr use="HP"&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine&gt;111111 Sw 53Rd St&lt;/streetAddressLine&gt;&lt;city&gt;AnyTown&lt;/city&gt;&lt;state&gt;FL&lt;/state&gt;&lt;postalCode&gt;33175&lt;/postalCode&gt;&lt;country&gt;United States of America&lt;/country&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;telecom use="HP" value="tel:111-222-5555"/&gt;&lt;patient&gt;&lt;name use="L"&gt;&lt;given&gt;Names&lt;/given&gt;&lt;family&gt;NamesNames&lt;/family&gt;&lt;/name&gt;&lt;administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" codeSystemName="HL7 AdministrativeGenderCodes" displayName="Male"/&gt;&lt;birthTime value="19500326"/&gt;&lt;maritalStatusCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.2" codeSystemName="MaritalStatusCode" displayName="Married"/&gt;&lt;raceCode code="2106-3" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.238" codeSystemName="Race &amp;amp; Ethnicity - CDC" displayName="White Hispanic"/&gt;&lt;sdtc:raceCode codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.238" codeSystemName="Race &amp;amp; Ethnicity - CDC" nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;sdtc:raceCode codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.238" codeSystemName="Race &amp;amp; Ethnicity - CDC" nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;ethnicGroupCode code="2135-2" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.238" codeSystemName="Race &amp;amp; Ethnicity - CDC" displayName="Hispanic"/&gt;&lt;languageCommunication&gt;&lt;languageCode code="spa"/&gt;&lt;preferenceInd value="true"/&gt;&lt;/languageCommunication&gt;&lt;/patient&gt;&lt;providerOrganization&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="Hospital" extension="Entity: EDA" root="2.16.840.1.114060.6.3.1.4.1"/&gt;&lt;name&gt;Hospital&lt;/name&gt;&lt;telecom use="WP" value="tel:111-111-2222"/&gt;&lt;addr use="WP"&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine&gt;11111 N 1st Avenue&lt;/streetAddressLine&gt;&lt;city&gt;AnyTown&lt;/city&gt;&lt;state&gt;FL&lt;/state&gt;&lt;postalCode&gt;12345&lt;/postalCode&gt;&lt;country&gt;United States of America&lt;/country&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;/providerOrganization&gt;&lt;/patientRole&gt;&lt;/recordTarget&gt;&lt;author&gt;&lt;time value="20140619191531-0400"/&gt;&lt;assignedAuthor&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="NPI" extension="1234567891" root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.6"/&gt;&lt;addr&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;city nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;state nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;postalCode nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;country nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;telecom value="tel:111-222-4444 ext:"/&gt;&lt;assignedPerson&gt;&lt;name&gt;&lt;given&gt;OthLastNamei&lt;/given&gt;&lt;family&gt;LastName-Man&lt;/family&gt;&lt;/name&gt;&lt;/assignedPerson&gt;&lt;representedOrganization&gt;&lt;id extension="W0CL" root="2.16.840.1.114060.6.3.1.4.1"/&gt;&lt;name&gt; Hospital &lt;/name&gt;&lt;telecom value="tel:111-111-2222"/&gt;&lt;addr&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine&gt;11111 N 1st Avenue&lt;/streetAddressLine&gt;&lt;city&gt;AnyTown&lt;/city&gt;&lt;state&gt;FL&lt;/state&gt;&lt;postalCode&gt;12345&lt;/postalCode&gt;&lt;country&gt;United States of America&lt;/country&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;/representedOrganization&gt;&lt;/assignedAuthor&gt;&lt;/author&gt;&lt;custodian&gt;&lt;assignedCustodian&gt;&lt;representedCustodianOrganization&gt;&lt;!-- OID is OID for Custodian hospital name --&gt;&lt;id extension="W0CL" root="2.16.840.1.114060.6.3.1.4.1"/&gt;&lt;name&gt;Hospital&lt;/name&gt;&lt;telecom value="tel:111-111-2222"/&gt;&lt;addr&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine&gt;11111 N 1st Avenue&lt;/streetAddressLine&gt;&lt;city&gt;AnyTown&lt;/city&gt;&lt;state&gt;FL&lt;/state&gt;&lt;postalCode&gt;12345&lt;/postalCode&gt;&lt;country&gt;United States of America&lt;/country&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;/representedCustodianOrganization&gt;&lt;/assignedCustodian&gt;&lt;/custodian&gt;&lt;documentationOf&gt;&lt;serviceEvent classCode="PCPR"&gt;&lt;effectiveTime&gt;&lt;low value="20140614"/&gt;&lt;high value="20140619"/&gt;&lt;/effectiveTime&gt;&lt;/serviceEvent&gt;&lt;/documentationOf&gt;&lt;componentOf&gt;&lt;encompassingEncounter&gt;&lt;id extension="000000123456" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19"/&gt;&lt;effectiveTime&gt;&lt;low value="201406141743"/&gt;&lt;high value="201406191843"/&gt;&lt;/effectiveTime&gt;&lt;encounterParticipant typeCode="CON"&gt;&lt;assignedEntity&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="NPI" extension="1111111111" root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.6"/&gt;&lt;addr use="WP"&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;city nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;state nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;postalCode nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;country nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;telecom use="WP" value="tel:123-123-1234 ext:"&gt;  &lt;/telecom&gt;&lt;assignedPerson&gt;&lt;name&gt;&lt;given&gt;John J&lt;/given&gt;&lt;family&gt;Snow&lt;/family&gt;&lt;/name&gt;&lt;/assignedPerson&gt;&lt;/assignedEntity&gt;&lt;/encounterParticipant&gt;&lt;encounterParticipant typeCode="ADM"&gt;&lt;assignedEntity&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="NPI" extension="1234567891" root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.6"/&gt;&lt;addr use="WP"&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;city nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;state nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;postalCode nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;country nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;telecom use="WP" value="tel:111-222-4444 ext:"&gt;  &lt;/telecom&gt;&lt;assignedPerson&gt;&lt;name&gt;&lt;given&gt;OthLastNamei&lt;/given&gt;&lt;family&gt;LastName-Man&lt;/family&gt;&lt;/name&gt;&lt;/assignedPerson&gt;&lt;/assignedEntity&gt;&lt;/encounterParticipant&gt;&lt;encounterParticipant typeCode="ATND"&gt;&lt;assignedEntity&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="NPI" extension="1234567891" root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.6"/&gt;&lt;addr use="WP"&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;city nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;state nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;postalCode nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;country nullFlavor="NI"/&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;telecom use="WP" value="tel:111-222-4444 ext:"&gt;  &lt;/telecom&gt;&lt;assignedPerson&gt;&lt;name&gt;&lt;given&gt;OthLastNamei&lt;/given&gt;&lt;family&gt;LastName-Man&lt;/family&gt;&lt;/name&gt;&lt;/assignedPerson&gt;&lt;/assignedEntity&gt;&lt;/encounterParticipant&gt;&lt;location&gt;&lt;healthCareFacility&gt;&lt;id assigningAuthorityName="Hospital" extension="hosp svc:EDA" root="2.16.840.1.114060.6.3.1.4.1"/&gt;&lt;location&gt;&lt;name&gt;Inpatient Via Ed-Eda&lt;/name&gt;&lt;addr use="WP"&gt;&lt;streetAddressLine&gt;11111 N 1st Avenue&lt;/streetAddressLine&gt;&lt;city&gt;AnyTown&lt;/city&gt;&lt;state&gt;FL&lt;/state&gt;&lt;postalCode&gt;12345&lt;/postalCode&gt;&lt;country&gt;United States of America&lt;/country&gt;&lt;/addr&gt;&lt;/location&gt;&lt;/healthCareFacility&gt;&lt;/location&gt;&lt;/encompassingEncounter&gt;&lt;/componentOf&gt;&lt;component&gt;&lt;structuredBody&gt;&lt;
```

For readability, the contents of the `<Ccd>` element, when unescaped (parsed), look like this:

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd">
  <realmCode code="US"/>
  <typeId extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
  <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2"/>
  <id root="2.25.126274596634328418155136651226877799755"/>
  <code code="34133-9" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Summarization of episode note"/>
  <title>Clinical Document Architecture</title>
  <effectiveTime value="20140619191531-0400"/>
  <confidentialityCode code="N" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25"/>
  <languageCode code="en-US"/>
  <recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <id assigningAuthorityName="Enterprise MPI Number" extension="000000001" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.1.2.1"/>
      <id assigningAuthorityName="Enterprise MPI Number" extension="000000001" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.1.2.1"/>
      <id assigningAuthorityName="SSN" extension="999999999" root="2.16.840.1.113883.4.1"/>
      <id assigningAuthorityName="Hospital: Locally defined Patient Account Number" extension="000222222222" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.44273.7.3"/>
      ...
```

Comment: please specify the sql db you are using because of difference in features

Comment: I assume you need the answer STAT!

Comment: :)  Well, turns out i have been pulling the wrong ID and that it is pulling the first one it finds.  The Source system is static, so I was thinking i could qualify on that, but xml can be fragile

Comment: The XML you posted isn't well-formed: it ends with an incomplete entity reference, and there are missing end tags. So it can't actually be an XML snippet that you're getting anything out of using XPath.

Comment: I added only the first section because I don't need the rest.  the section is the first part WHEN 'CCD'.  I just can't seem to make it go passed the first one.  The one i want is in the 4th id/@extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement

```
WHEN 'CCD' THEN @xmlData.value('(hl7ns:ClinicalDocument/hl7ns:recordTarget/
                  hl7ns:patientRole/hl7ns:id/@extension)[1]', 'varchar(128)')
```

selects, as you say, the first patientRole/id/@extension (because of the `[1]`). But you want the locally defined patient id, i.e.

```
  <id assigningAuthorityName="Hospital: Locally defined Patient Account Number" 
       extension="000222222222" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.44273.7.3"/>
```

So you could change your WHEN statement's XPath expression to filter based on the value of the `assigningAuthorityName` attribute:

```
WHEN 'CCD' THEN @xmlData.value('(hl7ns:ClinicalDocument/hl7ns:recordTarget/
   hl7ns:patientRole/hl7ns:id[
      assigningAuthorityName="Hospital: Locally defined Patient Account Number"]/
     @extension)[1]', 'varchar(128)')
```

(broken up so you don't have to scroll sideways).

This will give you the `@extension` of the first `<id>` whose `assigningAuthorityName` is `"Hospital: Locally defined Patient Account Number"`.

Comment: So if I want to pull in patient IDs from multiple facilities, would i put an OR i.e :  <id assigningAuthorityName="Hospital: Locally defined Patient Account Number" 
       extension="000222222222" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.44273.7.3"/> or <id assigningAuthorityName="Hospital 2: Locally defined Patient Account Number" 
       extension="000222222222" root="1.3.6.1.4.1.26923.99.1.1.44273.7.3"/>

Comment: @user3739288: um... you're talking about modifying the input XML?

Comment: Your code was spot on, but instead of setting according to assigning auth, i noticed it was consistently in the [4], so i created a function with [4] and added that to the column.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks Lars!

Comment: @user3739288: Glad you got it to work. I was avoiding the `[4]` because of what you said about "XML is fragile"... I thought you were trying to be careful not to use a less robust expression. Anyway, if you know it works on all your input, great.